# listview item tooltip text is behind topmost form?

Tags: c#, .net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsKTq.png

I am using a normal listView that is in a form.

My form TopMost property is set to true.

When I hover my mouse over an item, the tooltip text is shown BEHIND the form!

I am positive I need to use WndProc in my form to detect one of the following & then making the tooltip topmost...But how? Please help!

```
        private const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
        private const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;
        private const int OCM__BASE = (WM_USER + 0x1c00);
        private const int OCM_NOTIFY = (OCM__BASE + WM_NOTIFY);
```

Comment: i think this thread has same problem discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478295/tooltip-appearing-behind-the-form-window-c-vs-2008

Comment: cause of topmost. easy solution, disabled it!